# Convert gremlin query compatible with CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Could you please help me to convert this query into a gremlin query compatible with CosmosDB? Unfortunately, I am getting `Gremlin op does not support by(traversal)` and looks like to be due to the version of Gremlin in CosmosDB.

Thank you.

Query

```
g.V().limit(10)
    .dedup()
    .as('node')
    .project('id', 'label', 'properties', 'edges')
    .by(__.id())
    .by(__.label())
    .by(__.valueMap().by(__.unfold()))
    .by(
        __.outE()
        .project('id', 'from', 'to', 'label', 'properties')
        .by(__.id())
        .by(__.select('node').id())
        .by(__.inV().id())
        .by(__.label())
        .by(__.valueMap().by(__.unfold()))
        .fold()
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that from that error message that a `by` with a Traversal inside it is not supported. So something like `by(outE()....)` is likley one of the issues. I am not super familiar with the Gremlin support that CosmosDB offers but they do document their support differences [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph/gremlin-support).

You will need to figure out which Gremlin constructs are supported in order to re-write the query. I am not sure if `elementMap` is supported, but if it is, that may be helpful in terms of getting the information about edges.